# Next Instance of Job Runs Before I Can Debug This Instance

Tags: airflow

When I'm developing on Airflow and turn my DAG on, it'd fail on, say, Step 6, and Steps 7-9 would not start. But before I can debug the issue, the next instance (I'm putting the start_date in the past) will start and run all the way to Step 5 and fail on Step 6, completely messing up my workflow. Is this behavior expected, or could it be turned off, such that the next instance doesn't start until this instance is green everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for the following two options you can set on the operators.

> depends_on_past (bool) – when set to true, task instances will run sequentially while relying on the previous task’s schedule to succeed. The task instance for the start_date is allowed to run.
>
> wait_for_downstream (bool) – when set to true, an instance of task X will wait for tasks immediately downstream of the previous instance of task X to finish successfully before it runs. This is useful if the different instances of a task X alter the same asset, and this asset is used by tasks downstream of task X. Note that depends_on_past is forced to True wherever wait_for_downstream is used.

Reference: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#models

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be a flag I was missing, and I think it's `wait_for_downstream`. I'm not understanding 'task instances will run sequentially while relying on the previous task’s schedule to succeed' for `depends_on_past` though. Does "previous task's schedule" refer to the previous task's instance or the task right before this one in the current instance?

Comment: Yes "previous task's schedule" would be for the DAG run right before.  Say we have a DAG with tasks (A) -> (B) -> (C) that runs once a day.  If set on (B), today's run will check if yesterday's run succeeded before proceeding, unless it is the first run all together.